# How do I easily convert an audiobook (.m4b) to a standard audio file?

Tags: itunes, ipod, macos

I have several audio dramas that are in the audiobook (.m4b) format in iTunes. My problem is that when I sync my 5th gen iPod to iTunes, they don't show up in Music>Playlists, they show up under Music>Audiobooks. This is really driving me crazy, because I want the audiobooks in Music>Playlists, but the only workaround is to convert them to a different format. How do I easily convert the audiobooks to a standard audio file format that *will* show up in Music>Playlists on my iPod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug around for quite a long time to find this answer and *finally* found out that under the info box, there is a drop-down menu in the Info box under Info>Options:

[image: iTunes>Info>Options]

And the drop-down menu allows you to choose where it will show up:

[image: Options>Media Kind]

All that converting was done for nothing...